# Camping's URL() doesn't give me "site root" as expected?

Tags: ruby, rack, stylesheet, camping

Due to circumstances beyond my control, my production Camping site appears at `mysite.example.com/mysite`.  I'm pretty sure this is a common Apache / Passenger configuration issue, and I'm not interested in how to fix it right now because the server is out of my control.  Suffice to say, the controller for "/" points there and I can't change that any time soon.

Now, for a long time, this wasn't an issue, because `R(MyIndexController)` points to the correct place.  However, I serve my site's CSS using a `Rack::Static` call to make $SITE_ROOT/public accessible.  This means that the stylesheet is at `mysite.example.com/mysite/css/style.css`.  Here's where the problem comes in: the Camping `URL()` method, when called in my layout, gives `http://mysite.example.com`, not `http://mysite.example.com/mysite`.  So I can't get it to point to the /css subdirectory, because it's missing a "hop" in the middle.  When I run rackup locally, everything is fine (because this file is at `localhost:8080/css/style.css`), but on the production server I don't know how to fix it.

My question: is there another method (maybe directly from Rack?) that I should be calling instead?  I really want to avoid hardcoding it, and/or having a hack to determine whether I'm running locally (for debug) or in production, for every rendering of the layout.

ETA: OK, this gets stranger.  Obviously I've abstracted out some of the actual details above, part of which I think I "over-scrubbed".  The "top level" URL is actually more akin to `/mysite/rest` (the developer-centric HTML presentation of our RESTful interface), as opposed to `/mysite/management` (accounts) or `/mysite/ui` (JQuery'd / "nice" UI).  These are set up in our config.ru, via `run Rack::URLMap.new(Hash['/rest' => RestModule, '/ui' => PrettyInterfaceModule, '/management' => UserManagerModule]`, etc.

So in answer to the comment below, R(Index), from a view in the RestModule, actually returns `/mysite/rest/`.  As an example, I have a "home" link in the layout, which looks like `a :href=>R(Index)`, and generates code that looks like `<a href="/mysite/rest/">`.  The server is configured to serve files from ./public directly at the "site root", so `./public/css/style.css` actually does apppear at `http://mysite.example.com/mysite/css/style.css`, as noted previously.  It's *that* link that I'm having trouble automatically generating, and it's because of the Rack::URLMap that I thought I may have to rely on a native Rack method (not a Camping abstraction) to locate this resource.

Comment: What does R(MyController) return? /mysite/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case, `URL()` actually returns `http://mysite.example.com/mysite/rest/`?
What about something like this?

```
URL().merge('../css/style.css')
```

Comment: I got a bit turned around there -- URL() returns *only* the base portion of the URL, as I said above `http://mysite.example.com`.  However, R(Index) returns `http://mysite.example.com/mysite/rest/`.  So I *could* try `R(Index).merge('../css/style.css')` but that feels kind of hacky.

Comment: oops, R(Index) actually returns relative paths, so it's `/mysite/rest`.  That means I'd need to use `URL(Index).merge('../css/style.css')` but the idea holds

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so I assume that you did already find a workaround but the new passenger + apache (or ngnix) behaves correctly for camping as far as I could replicate. Your app would be on the Documents root and all the includes in the /public folder so /public/css should be routed correctly regardless of you using a sub folder /mysite or not as passenger doesn't make a difference (again) as far as I can replicate. Therefore this should be easily solvable with passenger 3 + Apache or ngnix.